# Task Forwarding in Workflow sap

Tags: workflow, abap, sap-fiori

I have forwarded travel expense approval task from one manager to
 another manager in sap fiori. Can anyone tell me how to get the
 current approver?

Thanks

Comment: Where do you want to see it? Just in an SAP transaction or do you need it in  a program? What have you tried so far?

Comment: I want to show the approver name in the account of person who has raised it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you able to use ABAP? Then this might solve your issue.
You need to enhance ABAP logic for this certain scenario in fiori.

1. determine your workflow, workitem id (wi_id)
2. determine current agent via

   ```
    CALL FUNCTION 'RH_USERS_OF_WI_READ' "Get Current Agents (Users) for Work Item
     EXPORTING
       wi_id =                     " swwuserwi-wi_id
     TABLES
       user_tab =                  " swhactor
     EXCEPTIONS
       NOTHING_FOUND = 1           "
        . "  RH_USERS_OF_WI_READ
   ```
3. use HROBJID of swhactor to determine personnel number or central person
4. read name of HROBJID e.g. via infotype table PA0001 (e.g. field ENAME)